# Jquery Dynamic Event firing from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the event associated with an element and try to trigger the respective event. For example if I pass an id for a textbox and it has an event focus binded with it, then I want to trigger that focus event. I know we can get the event details by using

```
     $.data('selector', 'events');
```

but how to use this object? This should be in jquery or javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why on Earth would you need this. Try [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

```
var item = $("selector"), 
    trigger = function(name){
        item.triggerHandler(name);
    };

$.each($.data(item[0], "events"), trigger);
```

**Warning** This code won't work with delegated events and such. It only triggers handlers bound to matched element.

Comment: Hi Can you like show me how should I use it when the remove functionality is called in http://jsfiddle.net/jshah11/QavKj/4/